# How to Predict Polynomial Regression Python with Nominal Data type

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas, polynomials

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

df = pd.read_csv("diamonds.csv")

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ["color", "clarity", "cut"])

X, Y = df.drop(labels = ["price", "color_E", "clarity_VS2", "cut_Good"], axis = 1).values, df[["price"]].values


pf = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2, include_bias = False)
pf.fit(X_train)
pf.transform(X_train)

pf.transform(X_train)

X_train_transformed = pf.transform(X_train)
X_test_transformed = pf.transform(X_test)

modelR = LinearRegression()
modelR.fit(X_train_transformed, Y_train)


predictionlist = [0.23, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 61.5, 55, 3.47, 3.58, 1.57]

print("Polynomial Regression score: " + str(modelR.score(X_test_transformed, Y_test)) + " prediction: " + str(modelR.predict(pf.fit_transform([predictionlist]))[0][0]))
```

And this is the output:

Polynomial Regression score: 0.96599715147751 prediction: -16308769.231718607

The Score of my Polynomial Regression is very good but my prediction is very bad, how can the price of a diamond be -16308769.231718607

I think my predictionlist is very messed up

Answer (score 0):

You messed up with your pf.transform. When printing your prediction you fit_transform, basically you fit your transformation only on one instance, the one you want to predict. Just fit_transform it on your train set, simply transform your test set and simply transform your predictionlist.

Comment: My prediction was the same after your changes

Comment: Is prediction list a single instance of your data?